# How to include data in a URL using Google script

Tags: url, google-apps-script

I want to pass data in my url using google apps script, here it is my doGet(e) function.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var spanish = LanguageApp.translate('This is a test', 'en', 'ar');

  return ContentService
           .createTextOutput(spanish);

}
```

Want i want to achieve is really simple.

what should i add in my function to make my url outPut include the three parameters (sourceLang , targetLang ,sourceText).

https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=...+sourceLang+targetLang+sourceText

i test several thing and i still getting the same url.

Please help and thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, @naima! Please, don't repost the question if it is pretty much the same as the [one you previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56727772/11407695) - it OK to edit the question however you see fit, just make sure we know that something is changed. Address the questions asked by TheMaster and @Tanaike to clarify your question and take a look at my comment as well - isn't it what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: i think that my question was changed, thank you oleg valter

Comment: Hi! Thanks for updating the question. Btw, have you read the [WebApps guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)? The "script.googleusercontent" URL is the URL from which the content output is server and should not be used otherwise - please, update the question with the end goal you are trying to achieve (I mean, why would you want the parameters to appear in the URL from which the `ContentService` servs text output?)